# can we encrypt %%emailaddr%% while passing to a page?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, security, encryption, content-builder

we pass %%emailaddr%% to a webpage as query string value.

Can we encrypt the email on email send and webpage can decrypt it so email is never exposed?

**NOTE:** In this case webpage is a 3rd party site page (not cloud page or microsite)

Answer (score 2):

You can base64 encode it with Base64 encode function, and decode it with javascript on the client side.

Reference:

- [Base64 Encode](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/Base64Encode.htm)
- [Base64 Decode JavaScript](https://gist.github.com/jarus/948005)

Comment: depending on the scenario/ organization base64 may not be deemed secure enough. if that's the case you could explore creating a API call to fetch the email address based on the subscriber key used.  [retreving data from a data extension](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/retrieving_data_from_a_data_extension.htm)